# Form data does not inserted to the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is my code for writing data to another database when the submit button is clicked. There are two buttons one accept and one deny, when accept is clicked it will write to a database called headforms and when deny is clicked, it will write the data to a database called deanforms. Please ignore the way i wrote the code because of my basic html/php/sql skills and it would be great if someone helped me!

```
    <?php
} else if ($usertype == 1) { 
$server = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$db = "";
$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$overrides = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$user1'"); 
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($overrides);
?>
    <?php
echo "&nbsp;Overrides today: " . $num_rows; 
?>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($overrides)) { ?>
    <fieldset>  <?php
         echo "First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Mid. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['mname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Fam. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['fname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Student ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['sid'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Scolarship:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['sc'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Phone No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Class:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['class'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Section:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['section'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Semester:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['semester'] . "<br />"; 
             $name = $row['name'];
         $mname = $row['mname'];
         $fname = $row['fname'];
         $sid = $row['sid'];
         $sc = $row['sc'];
         $phone = $row['phone'];
         $email = $row['email'];
         $class = $row['class'];
         $section = $row['section'];
         $semester = $row['semester'];
         ?>
<br />
<div>
<label for="comments" accesskey="c">Notes & Comments:</label><br />
<textarea name="comments" cols="35" rows="10">
</textarea><br>
</div>
<br>
            <form method="post" action="dbheads.php" name="HeadWritingForm" id="HeadWritingForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Accept" /><br><br>
        </form>
                <form method="post" action="dbheads2.php" name="deny" id="deny" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Deny" /><br><br>
    </form>

    </fieldset>
    <br>
<?php    }
?>
<br />
```

my dbheads.php

```
    <?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());


$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `headforms`(`name`,`mname`,`fname`,`sid`,`email`,`phone`,`sc`,`class`,`section`,`semester`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("ssssssssss", $name, $mname, $fname, $sid, $email, $phone, $sc, $class, $section, $semester);
$prepare->execute();   
if ($prepare) {
echo 'accepted';
} else {
echo 'sorry';
}
?>
```

my dbheads2.php

```
    <?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());


$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `deanforms`(`name`,`mname`,`fname`,`sid`,`email`,`phone`,`sc`,`class`,`section`,`semester`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("ssssssssss", $name, $mname, $fname, $sid, $email, $phone, $sc, $class, $section, $semester); 
$prepare->execute();   
if ($prepare) {
echo 'denied';
} else {
echo 'Sorry';
}
?>
```

When accept is clicked, it prints on the page accepted and when deny is clicked, it prints denied but no writing to the database is done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In dbheads.php and dbheads2.php you're mixing API's (`mysql_` and `mysqli_`) which will never work.Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: you're not checking return values of functions called

Comment: firstly this `<?php
} else if ($usertype == 1) {` is that part of something bigger, say on TOP of that? Plus, I take it you've started the session? No? Well do. You're also mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()` that doesn't mix with `mysqli_`. *Sigh,* if only it could.

Comment: plus, `<textarea name="comments" cols="35" rows="10">` is outside your form tags.

Comment: In your dbhead files I see you using a bunch of variables but not the $_POST values (unless you have register globals on, yikes). You need to set all those variables to the value from `$_POST['field_name']`. And I would suggest also validating the posted values because there will still be some issues with blanks and length (data larger than column width).

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes part of something bigger but its something else i dont think it will matter since it worked a while ago and stopped now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- im not adding comments to the database for now so it shouldnt matter should it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard fixed the sql to sqli and it doesnt report any errors.

Comment: probably not (for now) but it will once you will want to. Plus, change `$prepare->execute();` to `if(!$prepare->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` to see if your queries are failing and what @JayBlanchard posted for error reporting.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn im not using POST since i already have  $name = $row['name']; etc...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Warning: there was an error....Column 'name' cannot be null in /home/aukwizcq/public_html/dbheads.php on line 12

Comment: there you go Sam. You'll need to find out why that is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i cant seem to find out why name is null...it was working just a while ago.

Comment: as I stated earlier; did you start the session? It's unknown whether `session_start();` is part of all your files using sessions, since it looks like it's related to the error where you'r'e using `$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];` I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- session is started im pretty sure. i have other code relying on that.

Comment: as stated earlier by @JonathanKuhn you're using forms with a POST method; why? if you're trying to pass something through your forms and using that to do something with your DB, then there's nothing else to support those. at this point, I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: You do still need to use $_POST. Setting the variables in your form page will not carry over to the dbhead pages if loaded separately. Also, I'm assuming `$row`  is from a database row. $_POST is the way to get the data from the form. You will *need* to use $_POST in order to get the values from the form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have fixed it thank you very much but one small question: now when i click deny or accept, it denies or accepts all the forms i have, i want it so the function would control single forms.

Comment: you're welcome. use `isset()` but seeing that I shouldn't be posting an answer, others have posted answers below and your question stands at never being properly closed; not on what the answers given below contain anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Prepared` is not null, it sounds like you have a database issue. Something in the database is not allowing you to write to it.

What would be very handy to you is to see what is going on the database side.

MySQL has a great feature that allows you to view the queries that have been executed and has helped me multiple times.

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Take a look at the table `mysql.general_log`:

```
select * from  mysql.general_log;
```

When you are done make sure you set `general_log = 'OFF';` so that the log doesn't grow constantly.

I usually clear the log before I turn the log on:

```
truncate mysql.general_log;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set $user = ""; as root(default) or whatever you have and also provide the database name like $db="your database name" so php can know if in which databse the data should insert or to which database it need to interact.

Comment: I'm sure they've left out those credentials.

Comment: even if they had the right credentials the code would fail.

Comment: credentials are right, i just removed it so i could post it here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard wondering if they're going to come up from behind.